# problems with own package index

Tags: python, buildout, pypi

I placed some eggs on my website to create my own package index:

http://mnowotka.kei.pl/eggs/

Now I would like to use this index in my buildout configuration:

```
[buildout]
...
find-links = ...
             http://mnowotka.kei.pl/eggs/
```

To make some packages from that index available for my local python interpreter:

```
[python]
...
eggs = ...
dashboard-common
```

However, while executing ./bin/buildout i get following error:

```
Couldn't find index page for 'dashboard-common' (maybe misspelled?)
Getting distribution for 'dashboard-dommon'.
While:
   Installing python.
   Getting distribution for 'dashboard-common'.
Error:
   Couldn't find a distribution for 'dashboard-common'.
```

Any ideas of what can be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in dash/underscore - in fact having underscore in egg name and dash in buildout requirement was correct. The source of the problem was in egg name - "...py2.7..." when I was using python, version 2.6 so biuldout didn't want do install this one. Because there was no alternatives I got this messages.

Answer (score 1):

Your egg is called http://mnowotka.kei.pl/eggs/dashboard_common-0.5-py2.7.egg, so with an underscore. dashboard_common. You're querying for dashboard-common with a dash.

Those two don't match, that's the problem. Look in your setup.py and adjust the name of the package to be dashboard-common. The package itself, the thing you import, can stay dashboard_common.

Comment: What setup.py? I'm using buildout, there is no setup.py file. In the package itself there is also no setup.py file so I don't know how to apply your advice.